# Java Service Wrapper environment variable reference issue

Tags: java, service, wrapper

I use Tanuki JSW to install and start a Java process in Windows XP Professional OS.
The JSW needs a system environment variable `WRAPPER_HOME` to start, so I configured it using usual Windows OS way (Right-click on My Computer >> Properties, etc.).

When I started JSW , it gives me this error:

> `_WRAPPER_HOME_\logs (The system cannot find the path specified. (0x3))".`

It works after system reboot. However, **my goal is to avoid rebooting the system.**

Is there a way that I can tweak JSW so that it gets `WRAPPER_HOME` without rebooting the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Enviroment Variables->System Variables->Set WRAPPER_HOME=yourPath. Then double check it executing cmd, then execute set. You variable should be there.

Comment: It did not work .. I repeat that I have no issue to setup and confirm environmental variable settings. I wonder if I have a way to tweak JSW wrapper to use environment variable without rebooting the system

Comment: In the documentation it says that you have to modify the  wrapper.conf file, I don't see any info on ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES on this. In this file, It says you should put the variables in this conf file. It also says that JBOSS don't set this variable by default (I guess neither does TOMCAT) and you have to create it in this file just like this. wrapper.logfile=../logs/wrapper.log http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/props-example-config.html Have you tried this? I hope this helps.
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks.I do the same as of now. However , I am interested to configure ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES in Windows OS because wrapper will be installed by our System administrator in production. I hate to let admin update the wrapper.conf as it is error-prone.Therefore, I prefer them to configure ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES in usual windows OS way and let wrapper picks them up.